# Hibernate embedded hierarchy

Tags: hibernate

I would like to embed an object in my entity. I.e. I would like to have the type in the same table as MyEntity

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity<T extends MyType> {
    @Id
    long id;

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "MY_TYP"))
    @AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "integer",
        metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(value = "ConcreteType", targetEntity = ConcreteType.class)
        })
    @JoinColumn(name = "MY_ENTITY_ID")
    T typ;
```

}

The entity would look something like above. This works if MyType is an entity hierachy. But I would like to embed the Type in my MY_ENTITY table.

So I would like something like:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity<T extends MyType> {
    @Id
    long id;

    @Embedded
    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "MY_TYP"))
    @AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "integer",
        metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
                @MetaValue(value = "ConcreteType", targetEntity = ConcreteType.class)
        })
    T typ;
```

}

With MyType:

```
public interface MyType {
}
```

and a ConcreteType

```
 @Embeddable
 @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
 public class ConcreteType implements MyType {
     long myField;
 }
```

Both objects should be saved in the same table.

Table: MY_ENTITY

Columns: ID, MY_TYP, MY_FIELD

Is there a way to achieve that?